# Events with different types and data

Tags: java, oop

I am writing a library in Java, which throws an event of different types with differing data depending on the type.

For example, here is the extended EventObject:

```java
public class FooEvent extends EventObject {
    private final int eventType;
    private final Object fooEventObject;

    public FooEvent(int type, Object obj){/*...*/}
    public int getEventType() {/*...*/}
    public int getEventObject() {/*...*/}
}
```

And here is how I my listener currently looks like:

```java
FooEventListener listener = new FooEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(FooEvent event) {
        switch(event.getEventType()) {
            case EVENT_TYPE_BAR:
                Bars bar = (Bars)event.getEventObject();
                /*work with Bar object...*/
                break;

            case EVENT_TYPE_GOO:
                Goo goo = (Goo)event.getEventObject();
                /*work with Goo object...*/
                break;

            /* etc ...*/
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if this is the right way of solving this problem (although I doubt it is, since the user of the library would need to know what type to cast to)  wherein I have different event types with objects and I do not want to go and make a different event & listener for each one.

Comment: It's not the right way anyway, if he can work with the contract (interfaces) instead of concrete implementation, that is the right way to go!

Comment: I would think that, if you have different event types, you would be handling different events. Maybe they are similar, but different none the less.
-- edit --
Or the answer that Bart gave below is the thing you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava's [EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained) provides a slightly different approach that can handle multiple event types.

There is unfortunately no easy solution to have a type safe event system with different types. You either have to have 1 listener / publishing implementation per type of you need to teach one side about all the event types that exist.

There is a way to remove the need for `instanceof` or `switch (type)` and casting though: the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

The pattern uses the fact that event objects know their own type which means they can call the right method. The downside is that you need a listener interface that contains all the types.

```
public class Test {

    abstract static class EventObject {
        protected abstract void deliver(EventListener listener);
    }

    static class AEvent extends EventObject {
        @Override
        protected void deliver(EventListener listener) {
            listener.onAEvent(this);
        }
    }

    static class BEvent extends EventObject {
        @Override
        protected void deliver(EventListener listener) {
            listener.onBEvent(this);
        }

    }

    interface EventListener {
        void onAEvent(AEvent event);

        void onBEvent(BEvent event);
        // ...
    }

    private static final EventListener LISTENER = new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBEvent(BEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Got B Event! " + event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAEvent(AEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Got A Event! " + event);
        }
    };

    private static void notifyListeners(EventObject event) {
        event.deliver(LISTENER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        notifyListeners(new AEvent());
        notifyListeners(new BEvent());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to solve this is with generics.

```
public class FooEvent<T> extends EventObject {
    private final T fooEventObject;

    public FooEvent(T obj){/*...*/}
    public T getEventObject() {/*...*/}
}


//usage
SomeType object = new SomeType();
new FooEvent<SomeType>(object);
```

Comment: Except in this case, when I make the listener, I would have to declare the override like this: `public void onDataChange(FooEvent<Bars> event)` or `public void onDataChange(FooEvent<Goo> event)` or whatever other object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a way to go, but not the cleanest way. You should create an abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractEventType<T> extends EventObject {}
```

and extend from that:

```
public abstract class FooEvent extends AbstractEventType<Foo> {}

public abstract class BarEvent extends AbstractEventType<Bar> {}
```

Then you need to fire different events and also have different event listeners based on the type:

```
public interface FooEventListener {
    public void onFooChange(FooEvent fooEvent);
}
```

etc.

If you want to stick with only one event type then you could at least move the code to determine the type to your framework and avoid pollution of the "business" code, by creating one handler method per type, e.g.

```
public interface MyEventListener {
    public void onFooChange(EventType<Foo> eventType);
    public void onBarChange(EventType<Bar> eventType);
}
```

Comment: Please read the last line of my post; I understand this is a solution, but it would require a new event/listener interface for each and every event (and future events), I was hoping for a more efficient solution,.

Comment: OK, I know, but to my mind this is still the cleanest way. You should keep the "ugly" code away from the production code.

Comment: I think its a question of design and what yoz want to achieve with that design. If you have just 2 or 3 different EVentTypes than it is no problem to let the user of your API check for the correct type. KIS, Keep it simple!

Comment: @ChristianSchack agreed. I updated my answer with a simpler solution.